# Rails not accounting for daylight savings time

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")
=> (GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)
```

...but right now, in LA it's GMT-07:00 because of DST. See http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=137

Is this a bug, an error in my settings, or am I creating the TimeZone object improperly? Can't seem to figure it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. Turns out the TimeZone object *does* have a concept of 'now':

```
tz = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")
=> (GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada) 
tz.parse('8:00AM')
=> Fri, 12 Oct 2012 08:00:00 PDT -07:00
```

So you can still create TimeWithZone objects with the proper offset using the TimeZone-- despite the fact that its to_s method displays the incorrect offset.

Comment: Is there any way i can disable day light saving in my rails app?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` objects have a concept of "now". You can initialize a TimeZone with whatever utc_offset in seconds from you want with `::create`:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.create("Pacific Time (US & Canada)", -(60 * 60 * 7))
#  => (GMT-07:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)
```

The concept of now in relation to daylight savings time makes more sense when dealing with `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` objects. When you make your Rails app time zone aware by setting the time zone in application.rb:

```
config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
```

...and you use `Time.zone.now`, the result will take into account daylight savings time, GMT-07:00. So at the time of this post:

```
Time.zone.now
=> Fri, 12 Oct 2012 07:03:51 PDT -07:00

Time.zone.now.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

Comment: That makes sense. But the problem remains: I need to create a time zone that does have a concept of 'now'. That time zone could turn out to be different depending on the user, so I'm not looking for a solution that relies on hard-coded config parameters.

Comment: Also, I'm aware it's possible to adjust the offset by manually checking Time.now.dst? and adding an hour if true. But I figured if Rails' Time.now can get the correct TimeZone, there has to be a way to do that for anywhere else in the country, regardless of app-specific settings.